# Selective Time Machine copy

Tags: time-machine

My Time Machine backup has 100+ dated backups.  What I'd like to be able to do is extract the backups for a particular folder to another location, with the result being like TM's archive (where multiple references to unchanged files are just links to 1 copy).  Effectively, this would be a copy of the original TM archive, but *only* for the selected folder (and it's subfolders).  Is there any utility which can do this?

Comment: Or perhaps I should ask if there is a utility that will behave *like* TM: take 2 folders, and make a copy of the 2nd folder with links into the 1st folder where files are identical...

Comment: Hmm.  I see where `ditto` will will preserve file hard links (but not directory hard links).  Other than losing the directory hard links, this could be a perfect result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ditto` didn't cut it, but `rsync` did.  It has a `--link-dest` option, that uses files in that folder as the base to link to for duplicates.  It's important that the source path for rsync end in `/`.

To prepare, in the location I'm going to store my copy, I create a symlink to the 1st archived folder I want to copy: `ln -s -h -f /Volumes/MyBook\ 2/Backups.backupdb/Mini/2012-08-02-003832/Macintosh\ HD/Users/jerrybarrington/pathtothefolder/ /Volumes/MyBook\ /Volumes/MyBook\ 2/CK2.backup/Last`.

Then to copy: `sudo rsync -a --delete --link-dest=/Volumes/MyBook\ 2/CK2.backup/Last/ /Volumes/MyBook\ 2/Backups.backupdb/Mini/2012-08-02-003832/Macintosh\ HD/Users/jerrybarrington/pathtothefolder/ /Volumes/MyBook\ 2/CK2.backup/2012-08-02-003832/`.

Lastly, update the symlink to point to the new copy: `ln -s -h -f /Volumes/MyBook\ 2/CK2.backup/2012-08-02-003832/ /Volumes/MyBook\ 2/CK2.backup/Last`.

For each subsequent copy, repeat step 2, changing both instances of `2012-08-02-003832` to the next date I want, and then repeat step 3.

see http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/ for my inspiration.